# Terminal Emulator adds viewpoint

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to connect to a linux server running Rocket Software D3 multivalue database on our network from my ubuntu 14.04 desktop.  The connection can be either telnet or ssh but, I need the ADDS Viewpoint emulator.  Does anyone know of a terminal software that includes ADDS Viewpoint emulation for ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few options for Windows.  Best choice is Accuterm running on Wine.  I'm using it with Xubuntu and it works fine.  Good luck.